# Remove existing data validation with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl ws.add_data_validation to add some validation to a cell in Excel.  However, I'm finding that if the cell has some previous validation in place then it doesn't seem to take the new validation when I subsequently open it in the Excel application.  If I manually clear the previous validation from the target file before I run the program then it takes the new validation fine.  My code is:

```
dv = DataValidation(type='list', formula="{0}!$B$2:$B$18".format(quote_sheetname('values')))
ws.add_data_validation(dv)

row = 3
while row <= ws.max_row:
    dv.add('F{}'.format(row))
    row += 1
```

I think I may need to remove the existing validation before doing the dv.add command but I can't see anything in the docs about removing pre-existing validation.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: There's certainly no API for this but you should be able to loop over the validations and remove the relevant ones.

Comment: having the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: @yeye Afraid not.  In the end I just had to add a manual task to clear the validation each time from the target file before running the script.  I haven't had to use it for a while I'll spend some more time on it next time I run it and update this question if I find a resolution.  Good luck with your issue - let me know if you crack it before I do. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The way I found to remove data validation:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidationList
ws.data_validations = DataValidationList()  # ws is the worksheet object.
```

Note: the code above would remove all data validation from the worksheet.

Comment: This is the solution in my case, I had a problem putting Data Validation on some Excel workbooks with Openpyxl so I needed a bot to clean out all the wrong DV for me. The answer given from kb2136 made a corrupt Excel file in my case, don't know for sure why this happen. Tested today, a few minutes ago, Openpyxl version 3.1.2 with Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to wipe out all data validation.
The solution, albeit indirect, is given [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html):

> Validations without any cell ranges will be ignored when saving a workbook.

So it basically boils down to:

```
for dv in workbook_object[worksheet_name].data_validations.dataValidation:
    if some_condition:
        dv.sqref = ''
```